# Why don't the User accounts created in my app remember the Role selected for them on sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, cancan

Hopefully someone can help me on this one, it's absolutely driving me crazy!

Basically, I have created an Authentication system on my app, using Devise and CanCan, which works fine. The problem arises when I try to assign a Role to a User on signup, the Users Role does not save, the sign-up is successful, but the User has no assigned Role. In my Console the Users Role comes up as nil!

I've set up a HABTM association between Users and Roles, and tried various options. Rails Console returns User Role:nil even if I input the role as a String in the sign-up form.

I am new to Rails and programming in general, would really appreciate some assistance people! Many Thanks in

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles



# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role_ids

def role?(role)
  return !!self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
end

end
```

Snippet from New Registration View:

```
<fieldset> 
<legend>Sign Up</legend>

<div class="inputs">
<%= f.input :username, :required => true, :autofocus => true %>
<%= f.input :email, :required => false, :autofocus => true %>
<%= f.input :password %>
<%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => "Confirm Password" %>
</div>

<div>
<%= f.input :roles, :required => true, :collection => Role.find(:all).collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ]}, :label => "Role" %>
</div>
```

Params

> ```
> Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create
> ```
>
> as HTML   Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign
>   up",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"1HCmfOVATkz/LbALboU+Z2Bg/lBQseVNB2NeAG7GPHc=",
>   "utf8"=>"✓",
>   "user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "username"=>"test", "role_ids"=>["2"],
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
>   "email"=>"test@test.com"}}
>
> [1m[35mRole Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT
>   "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE
>   "roles"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1   [1m[36mSQL
>   (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 FROM "users"
>   WHERE ("users"."email" =
>   'test@test.com') LIMIT 1[0m
>   [1m[35mAREL (0.3ms)[0m  INSERT INTO
>   "users" ("reset_password_token",
>   "role", "email",
>   "remember_created_at",
>   "current_sign_in_ip",
>   "encrypted_password", "updated_at",
>   "created_at", "sign_in_count",
>   "username", "last_sign_in_at",
>   "reset_password_sent_at",
>   "last_sign_in_ip",
>   "current_sign_in_at") VALUES (NULL,
>   NULL, 'test@test.com', NULL, NULL,
>   '$2a$10$8J6F2NgkK6Tas0AVMiocUujimZ7K3XcYFSmWGeYUzmGDN55WVUHxO',
>   '2011-07-10 23:30:45.820893',
>   '2011-07-10 23:30:45.820893', 0,
>   'test', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
>   [1m[36mSQL (0.1ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO
>   "roles_users" ("role_id", "user_id")
>   VALUES (2, 33)[0m   [1m[35mAREL
>   (0.1ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET
>   "current_sign_in_ip" = '127.0.0.1',
>   "updated_at" = '2011-07-10
>   23:30:45.827053', "sign_in_count" = 1,
>   "last_sign_in_at" = '2011-07-10
>   23:30:45.826761', "last_sign_in_ip" =
>   '127.0.0.1', "current_sign_in_at" =
>   '2011-07-10 23:30:45.826761' WHERE
>   "users"."id" = 33
>
> Redirected to
>   http://localhost:3000/ Completed 302
>   Found in 163ms

Comment: would it be possible for you to give me an example of what you mean, I have tried this method and methods shown in various tutorials and nothing helps...however when I make the roles section of the form like the following, I don't get the association type mismatch but it still doesn't assign a role to the user:     <% for role in Role.find(:all) %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag "user[role_ids][]", role.id, @user.roles.include?(role) %>
      <%= role.name %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

Comment: could you please post the params?

Comment: apologies if I am being dim! -which params?

Comment: :) in your logs {"commit"=>"Sign up", "authenticity_token"=>"81y79qcxoxmh/eKOM6ugM//h2jPcl85qzrxKHTDuglg=", "utf8"=>"âœ“", ....

Comment: sorry! added to the end of question! thanks for your time man!

Comment: You're welcome. The console show it should work. see: `INSERT INTO "roles_users" ("role_id", "user_id") VALUES (2, 33)` Why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: It should let the new user i created with the role of super user manage all items but it doesn't! Also in my console, User Role still shows nil!

Comment: but did you try: `User.find(33).roles` in console?

Comment: Okay, sorry man, it is working, the problem is with the Role "Super User" In my abilities model I have if user.role? :super_user
          can :manage, :all       -I don't think it likes "super user" written as super_user! How am I supposed to put it?

Comment: Thanks for your help man, I figured out a workaround for that problem...I think that the advice you gave me earlier helped resolve the initial issue though! Really appreciate your time at this hour! Sorry that I can't vote up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many investigations, this question raised another question but no real here.

Comment: Hi mate, when I do that I get: association Type Mismatch error.. Role(#2172989180) expected, got String(#2148287480)  {"commit"=>"Sign up",
 "authenticity_token"=>"81y79qcxoxmh/eKOM6ugM//h2jPcl85qzrxKHTDuglg=",
 "utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "username"=>"test",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "roles"=>"2",
 "email"=>"test@test.com"}}